# ZF2 How to access event manager in controller's constructor

Tags: constructor, controller, zend-framework2

How to access event manager in controller constructor ? when I call event manager in constructor , this error appears :

Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have access to the service manager at this point, as it's injected once the object has been instantiated.

You could always move you code to be triggered onDispatch() rather than in the contructor:

```
/**
 * Execute the request
 *
 * @param  MvcEvent $e
 * @return mixed
 * @throws Exception\DomainException
 */
public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e)
{
    // do something here
    // or you could use the events system to attach to the onDispatch event
    // rather than putting your code directly into the controller, which would be 
    // a better option

    return parent::onDispatch($e);
}
```

I would just use Events to attach what ever you need, rather than using the controller

Module.php

```
/**
 * Initialize
 * 
 * @param \Mis\ModuleManager 
 */
public function init(ModuleManager $manager)
{
    $events = $manager->getEventManager();
    $sharedEvents = $events->getSharedManager();
    $sharedEvents->attach(__NAMESPACE__, 'dispatch', function($e) {
        /* @var $e \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent */
        // fired when an ActionController under the namespace is dispatched.
        $controller = $e->getTarget();
        $routeMatch = $e->getRouteMatch();
        /* @var $routeMatch \Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteMatch */
        $routeName = $routeMatch->getMatchedRouteName();

        // Attach a method here to do what you need

    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: Despite the fact of answer's age, I'd like to know, once you've done some work in module.php 's  `// Attach a method here to do what you need` using a method, 
How to get that results/data passed to the target controller?